# [FATAL] : ASSERTION FAILED When trying to use CameraPublisher

Tags: image-transport

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I've been trying to publish camera topics and when publishing image and camera_info topics with image_transport::CameraPublisher, using

```
image_transport::CameraPublisher left_image_pub;

left_image_pub.publish(left_image,left_cam_info);
```

I get:

```
[FATAL] [1427371749.536180328]: ASSERTION FAILED
    file = /tmp/buildd/ros-hydro-image-transport-1.11.4-0precise-20150101-0635/src/camera_publisher.cpp
    line = 126
    cond = false
    message = 
[FATAL] [1427371749.536421266]: Call to publish() on an invalid image_transport::CameraPublisher
[FATAL] [1427371749.536482747]: 

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could help me, because I tryied a lot to search about this subject but with no success.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205959/%5Bfatal%5D-:-assertion-failed-when-trying-to-use-camerapublisher/) by [aba92](https://answers.ros.org/users/21911/aba92/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2015-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your publisher is empty/invalid. You need to advertise some topic to somewhere, otherwise: Where should the messages go to? Check the beginner tutorials for how to do that.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0